# Split String with new line and add in array in PL sql Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a string like below:

> Hello Tom
>
> Where are you
>
> What's your name

I want to split the above string with new line and add to array as below
:

> [Hello Tom,Where are you,What's your name]

Is this possible in PL/SQL ?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you ask Tom's name again when you have already said hello to him?

Anyways.. Yes. You could use the standard string split operation on string delimited by `CHR(10)` - newline character in Oracle. Then make  use of `CAST` and `COLLECT` functions to convert it to an array. Here I have used Oracle's built-in collection `sys.OdciVarchar2List`. In your PL/SQL block you may BULK COLLECT it into any proper collection type that can hold string elements.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/763)

```
WITH t (s)
AS (
    SELECT 'Hello Tom
Where are you
What''s your name'
    FROM DUAL
    )
SELECT CAST ( COLLECT ( REGEXP_SUBSTR(s, '[^' || CHR(10)|| ']+', 1, LEVEL) )
                       AS sys.OdciVarchar2List )  as collection
FROM t CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(s, '[^' || CHR(10)|| ']+')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/763/0)**:

```
|                               COLLECTION |
|------------------------------------------|
| Hello Tom,Where are you,What's your name |
```

Answer (score 1):

Kaushik is probably right and I'm probably wrong, but that's what I understood (by looking at what the OP enclosed into square brackets, as a desired result):

```
SQL> WITH t (s)
  2  AS (SELECT 'Hello Tom
  3  Where are you
  4  What''s your name'
  5      FROM DUAL
  6      )
  7  select replace(s, chr(10), ',') result
  8  from t;

RESULT
----------------------------------------
Hello Tom,Where are you,What's your name

SQL>
```