# How to write multiset SELECT query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Consider below tables:

T_WORK

```
-------------------
| Work_id | Cre_d |
-------------------
|    1    | 2016  |
|    2    | 2017  |
|    3    | 2018  |
-------------------
```

T_WORK_PARAM

```
-----------------------------------
| Work_id | Param_nm | Param_val  |
-----------------------------------
|    1    |    Name  | John       |
|    1    |    Place | London     |
|    1    |    Date  | 01-01-2018 |
|    2    |    Name  | Trump      |
|    2    |    Place | Newyork    |
|    2    |    Date  | 02-02-2018 |
-----------------------------------
```

I need an output in below format

```
-----------------------------------
|         |    Name  | John       |
|    1    |    Place | London     |
|         |    Date  | 01-01-2018 |
-----------------------------------
|         |    Name  | Trump      |
|    2    |    Place | Newyork    |
|         |    Date  | 02-02-2018 |
-----------------------------------
```

In Oracle, I can achieve this with this query:

```
SELECT 
    T1.Work_id,
    CAST (MULTISET (SELECT Param_nm, Param_val
                    FROM T_work_param T2
                    WHERE T2.Work_id = T1.Work_id) AS type_param_tbl)
FROM 
    T_work T1
```

Where `type_param_tbl is table of (Param_nm varhar2(1000), PAram_val varhar2(1000));`

How to write a similar query in SQL Server ?

If it is not possible in SQL Server - what is the best/usual way to return the desired output to the caller (web service)?

Comment: Are you sure you get that output  using the query you have shown in Oracle?

Comment: Yes,that's a common way of doing it.

Comment: Could you paste the output from the query editor / tool where you tried and got the output in Oracle? I really want to see it.

Comment: I can't show you the output using sqlfiddle as it doesn't support table types. You  follow below stapes in Oracle. Step1. Create type type_param_obj is object (param_name varchar2(100) ,param_val varchar2 (1000)). Step2. Create type type_param_tbl is table of type_param_obj. Step3. Execute query given in the question.

Comment: Yes, that was my question, did you see that output in `sqlplus`, sql developer or through java code?

Comment: Yes man. I have seen the output. I have been using such query since many years now in my projects. If you have any doubts you may search for cast multiset in Google.

Comment: Ok. Please don't mind.. It is not that I have not used or known `collect` and it does show output for single records in sqlfiddle, here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967381/split-string-with-new-line-and-add-in-array-in-pl-sql-oracle. I just wanted to know which tool in particular gives the output in that form for this case. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

The way to achieve the result the way you want is actually by pivoting the `Param_nm` column. This will produce your result into a tabular format where you could parse/map it into your application.

Please, click [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fd484/6) for see a SQLFiddle that shows what I'm talking about.

I hope this may help you!

Comment: But what if Param name is not limited only for 3 types.

Comment: @KishorKumar If you know what are going to be all yours `param names`, then you could modify the pivot query for include those values. However, in case you'll receive a bunch of `param names`, then you should use a **dynamic pivot table**. Click [here](https://www.essentialsql.com/create-dynamic-pivot-table-sql-server/) for get more information about _dynamic pivot table_.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot do that in SQL server.

You may consider just joining the tables for somewhat similar result.

Comment: What is the best/usual way to return the desired output to the caller (webservice).?